# Lenses and benefit of exact fourier transform

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

I have learned in an Optics class that a lens will "compute" the Fourier Transform of an electromagnetic wave passing through it at the focal point behind it (but with a quadratic phase). However, doing the math you see that this lens will give the *exact* Fourier Transform at the same point of your signal if sent at focal distance before the lens.

Considering the fact that the eye doesn't see any difference in a phase variation, why is this exact Fourier Transform interesting ?

[I already see one reason : There is a technique called "Schlieren Method" that allows to actually *see* the phase variations in a signal, using multiple Fourier Transforms and the convolution theorem. (I was amazed by the idea and the fact.) In this case it is crucial to have an exact Fourier Transform, the quadratic phase making the all thing less more complicated. I was actually looking for some other examples.]

Does anyone have any idea ?

EDIT : 
For clarification (I hope making it clearer), what I mean by "quadratic phase", is the phase preceding $A$ in the following equation :

Assuming an incoming (2D) wave propagating in the $z$ direction from $x=d$, of wave length $\lambda=\frac{2\pi}{k}$ and of amplitude $a(x;z)$, the lens of focal distance $f$, being placed at $z=0$ (after $d$), we find : 
\begin{equation}a(x;f)\propto \sqrt{\frac{k}{f}}\exp\left(i\frac{k}{2f}x^2\left[1-\frac{d}{f}\right]\right)A\left(\frac{kx}{f};-f\right)\end{equation}

where I have written

\begin{equation}A(\rho;z)=e^{ikz}\int{a(x;0)e^{-i\rho x}dx}\end{equation}

I was wondering if there was another point than that of the Schlieren method to use an exact Fourier Transform of your initial signal $a$ (without the complex phase in front of it).

Comment: What is your question?   The Fourier Transform converts phase and angle info into position and intensity info.  That's what the eye (or photo film) detects.

Comment: Your question is confusing, could you elaborate?  Further, what do you mean by the square phase?

Comment: @roybatty : Sorry, I meant quadratic phase. Just edited.

Comment: It's interesting for a lot of reasons.  The most obvious to me is that the fourier transform image maps the spatial frequency content of the original image.  Not only is that interesting, but it is also useful because by placing a spatial filter at the fourier transform plane and then re-imaging, you can create a very selective spatial frequency filter.

Comment: And again a quadratic phase would make this kind of precise filters impossible. I think I've got my answer. Thank you.